# Redefine the text that appears in a reference to a label?

Tags: enumitem, ref

I am trying to use a custom list enviroment but am facing an issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{steps}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[steps, 1]{label = Step \arabic*:}
\begin{document}
\begin{steps}
  \item Initialize counter to 10.\label{loop} 
  \item Decrement counter by 1.
  \item If counter $\neq 0$ go back to \ref{loop}, else continue.
  \item Exit.
\end{steps}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The colon from the enumeration label definition is appearing in the reference as well. Is there someway I can remove this? Thanks!

Comment: enumitem offers the ref key for this `ref=Step \arabic*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`label` and `ref` may be different:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\newlist{steps}{enumerate}{1}
%\setlist[steps, 1]{label = Step \arabic*:}
\setlist[steps, 1]{label = Step \arabic*:, ref={\arabic*}}

\begin{steps}
  \item Initialize counter to 10.\label{loop} 
  \item Decrement counter by 1.
  \item If counter $\neq 0$ go back to \ref{loop}, else continue.
  \item Exit.
\end{steps}
\end{document}
```

[image]